# Free .NET sFTP component supporting asynchronous uploads?

Tags: .net, sftp

Are there any out there? I've done a fair bit of searching. Looks like there are some options for a few hundred $US++ but I can't see any free ones.

Answer (score 2):

There is one at www.example-code.com/csharp/ftp_asyncUpload.asp. I haven't used it myself. There is also http://www.eldos.com/sbb/ which has a free trial version with a nag screen. I have used this one but not for asynchronous uploading, but you could do the work in a delegate and use BeginInvoke to make it asynchronous.

Comment: it seems that those are for FTP, not SFTP

Comment: The www.eldos.com one definitely does SFTP. I have used it for that.

Comment: further to my previous comment http://www.sftp.net/sftp-net-vb-sample.html is a VB.NET example

Answer (score 0):

JFYI: SecureBlackbox (mentioned in previous answer) has TElSFTPClient component which can be used in asynchronous mode (in fact, async mode is the main one for TElSFTPClient).